# Password/Key protection

Tags: asp.net, security, cryptography, web-config

I am implementing payment gateways and I need to protect its key and password for security reason. Also some web-services keys and password in ASP.NET.

Any ideas on how to implement them?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt/decrypt using RSA Encryption.
It's a secure way and uses asymmetric cryptography.

- In JavaScript you can use [RSA In JavaScript by ohdave](http://ohdave.com/rsa/)
- And in ASP.NET you can use [this implementation](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/692-RSA-Encryption-C.aspx)